# How to sort files' names in Python

Tags: python, file

I have 2 directories left and right that contain files: `image1.jpg, image4.jpg, image2.jpg ... image131.jpg`

I'd like to put those names in sorted lists `all`, `left_files`, `right_files`.
The following program makes unordred lists `all`, `left_files`, `right_files` :

```
all = []
left_files = []
right_files = []
if os.path.exists(dir):
    for path, names, files in os.walk(dir):
        names.sort()

        for f in files:
            if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in ['.bmp', '.png', '.jpg', '.ppm']:
                if 'left' in f or 'left' in path:
                    left_files.append( os.path.join( path, f ) )
                elif 'right' in f or 'right' in path:
                    right_files.append( os.path.join( path, f ) )
                all.append( os.path.join( path, f ) )
```

When I use `sorted(left_files)`, it gives me files `image1.jpg, image10.jpg, image100.jpg`, but I want to obtain `image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg...`

Comment: you can use `glob.glob` to get a list of the files in that directory, then use `list.sort` to sort them however you'd like

Comment: Also if there are only two directories left and right , os.listdir("left") should be the choice.

Comment: I suggest you look at the NatSort package: https://pypi.org/project/natsort/